# Extract the value of a X.509 certificate custom extension using PyOpenSSL

Tags: python, x509, pyopenssl

Using Python and PyOpenSSL, is there a way to retrieve the value of a custom extension? By custom extension, I mean an extension encoded using the arbitrary extension format described under ARBITRARY EXTENSIONS at http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html.

Also, is it possible to create a certificate that contains such an extension using PyOpenSSL?

If the answer to either of these is "no", I would also be interested in pointers on how to do this with any other Python library. I do not want to perform system calls to the OpenSSL command line app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get any and all extensions on an X.509 certificate you've loaded using pyOpenSSL.  For example:

```
>>> from OpenSSL import crypto as c
>>> cert = c.load_certificate(c.FILETYPE_PEM, file('server.pem').read())
>>> cert.get_extension_count()
4L
>>> ext = cert.get_extension(0)
>>> ext.get_short_name()
'basicConstraints'
>>> ext.get_data()
'0\x00'
>>>
```

The data comes out in its raw format (some encoding of ASN.1, perhaps depending on the specific extension).

You can also add extensions.

```
>>> newext = c.X509Extension('nsComment', 0, 'tacos are delicious')
>>> cert.add_extensions([newext])
>>> cert.get_extension_count()
5L
>>> cert.get_extension(4)
<X509Extension object at 0x7f74db7c2290>
>>> cert.get_extension(4).get_data()
'\x16\x13tacos are delicious'
>>>
```

However, note the slight asymmetry.  The extension data must be a string and is encoded using ASN.1 automatically.  This seems to preclude the possibility of adding arbitrary non-string extension data.

Comment: Any suitable way to decode the raw data of extensions?

Comment: The somewhat recent `asn1crypto` library might be useful for that.

Comment: OK, Thanks for replied

Answer (score 2):

get any extension on an X.509 certificate, For example get subjectAltName:

```
cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, open(certName).read()) 
for index in range(cert.get_extension_count()):                                                                                                                                                         
        ext = cert.get_extension(index)                                                                                                                                                                          
        if 'subjectAltName' == ext.get_short_name():                                                                                                    
            print(str(ext))
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: This solution has already been posted in another answer, but thank you for answering.